# Reading/Writing doesn't recognize characters from/to .txt file C#

Tags: c#, encoding, filestream, read-write

I have a problem when I want to read/write these characters (á ð é í ó ú ý þ æ ö) from/to txt file.

I try it with FileStream, and in the both case I encode this to these characters (ß ­ Ú Ý ¾ · ² Ÿ µ ÷)

```
TxtFileModelInfo modelInfo = new TxtFileModelInfo();
TxtExporter export = new TxtExporter(modelInfo);
try
{                
    using (var outstream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        foreach (var obj in objects)
        {
            export.ExportObject(obj, outstream);
        }
    }                
}

TxtFileModelInfo modelInfo = new TxtFileModelInfo();
TxtImporter importer = new TxtImporter(modelInfo);
try
{                                               
    using (var instream = new FileStream(fileName,FileMode.Open))
    {                
      List<ApplicationObject> objects = importer.ImportFromStream(instream);
      if (objects != null && objects.Count > 0)
      {
          return objects;
      }
      else
      {
          Console.WriteLine(@"Object could not be readed from file {0}", 
          fileName);
      }                
  }
```

}

If anybody have some tips, I would be grateful.

Comment: How are you writing/reading from the stream?

Answer (score 1):

`FileStream` reads or writes only primitive types (like byte array), you will need a `StreamReader` and a `StreamWiter` to use any encoding.

For example to read data, you would use it like this:

```
using(var instream  = new FileStream(filename,FileMode.Open)) {
    using(var sr = new StreamReader(instream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)) {
        //do your work here
    }
}
```

Writing to a file is the same, except that you use a `StreamWriter`:

```
using(var outstream = new FileStream(filename,FileMode.Create)) {
    using(var sw = new StreamWriter(outstream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)) {
        //do your work here
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this but still have a problem with export.ExportObject(obj, outstream) and this importer.ImportFromStream(instream) because he expected Stream type parameter

Comment: @tomasevicstefan: You should use `sw` in the export (like `export.ExportObject(obj, sw);`), which is of stream type. But I cannot really help you there, since `TxtExporter` isn't part of any standard library.